# user accessing and permission denied

Tags: permissions, users, fedora

I had a user john in fedora 19

```
usergroup marygroup
useradd -g marygroup mary
usermod -a -G marygroup john
```

In John terminal:

```
cd /home/mary
```

Permission denied

```
cd /home

ls -l
drwx------. 11 john john
drwx------. 11 mary marygroup
logged into as root
chmod 770 /home/mary
ls -l
drwx------. 11 john john
drwxrwx---. 11 mary marygroup
```

still cannot do cd 
Permission denied why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By executing `chmod 770 /home/mary` all you did was set Read-Write-Execute permission for the Owner User and Owner Group of `/home/mary` folder (which is mary and marygroup).

If you want to access mary's home as john, you need to add user `john` to group `marygroup`:

```
$ gpasswd -a john marygroup`
```

For this to take effect, you will have to relogin as user `john`.

Comment: Thanks,Then why the following command will not solve the problem.         usermod -a -G marygroup john. Upto my knoweledge it is also adding to the supplementary groups.What is the difference between the 2 commands.

Comment: You need to relog with user `john` for new groups to take effect.